# Thunderbolt to multiple non-apple monitors

Tags: mac, external-display, displayport, thunderbolt

I've found several Q&A barely touching this option, and therefore no fairly usable answer.
I do have Macbook Pro 13" 2012'mid (not retina) with Thunderbolt port.
I'd like to use from 3-6 monitors (as much as possible) with at least Full HD resolution.
Is there currently (or in near future) option how to achieve this without using Apple Thubderbolt display?

**The best I could come up with** is to use Thunderbolt powered PCI-Express expansion box (eg [this](http://www.magma.com/thunderbolt) or [this](http://www.sonnettech.com/product/echoexpresschassis.html)), use some kind of good graphics card (or multiple) and connect the monitors to these graphics cards.

Aren't there some non-apple monitors daisy chained with thunderbolt (or DisplayPort) ?
Or if you can come up with more simple/cheaper solution than me.
I'll be thankfull for any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DisplayPort, depending on the version, does not support daisy chaining displays (later versions *might*, but no MacBooks I know of support it).

Thunderbolt does, but its limited by the graphics chips in the machines AND the MIDDLE monitor has to be a Thunderbolt-compliant display.  I.e. You can go:

```
MBP->Thunderbolt->[Generic DisplayPort Display]
```

but you can't go:

```
MBP-> [Generic DisplayPort Display] -> Thunderbolt
```

And that's assume you could find a DP Display that even had the option to do a daisy chain (i.e. has an output port as well as an input port).

Every official document I've read about displays and Thunderbolt and every test case I've seen around the internet has showed you're limited to two displays + the internal display on a Macbook Pro, and those were typically 15" models with dedicated graphics.  I wouldn't be surprised if the crappy INtel graphics in the 13" models restricted them to 1 external display.

If you're needing to support so many non-thunderbolt displays, the only Mac that will get you there reliably (and with anything resembling support) is a Mac Pro.